# Wordpress Emails Sending To Wrong Mail Server

Tags: wordpress, email, contacts, contact-form-7, bluehost

Using Contact Form 7 on Wordpress (or other contact plugins) it sends the email to the wrong email server.

A few months ago the non-profit I work for switched from the email integrated with BlueHost to G-Suite for non-profits. When someone fills out a form on our website though it sends to our old email server. So we miss any messages coming through our website. All other mail sends and receives correctly through Gmail. It is only mail sent from our Wordpress site. I have tried other form plugins and they have the same issue.

I have tried searching for a solution but I haven't been able to find answers. I assume it is an issue with Wordpress or Bluehost, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue ended up being with the web host (even though they blamed CloudFlare). The mail DNS was setup properly through CloudFlare. However, since it hadn't been changed through BlueHost's DNS settings, it was still sending to the wrong mail server.